# Solving $a^2-4b^2 = 101$

Tags: number-theory

> How do you solve $a^2-4b^2 = 101$ in positive integers $a,b$?

I didn't see a nice way of solving this and was wondering if there was an easy way of find the solutions.

Answer (score 9):

Hint: Observe
\begin{align}
a^2-4b^2 = (a-2b)(a+2b) = 101
\end{align}
and note $101$ is prime.

Answer (score 0):

From this : $a^2−4b^2=(a−2b)(a+2b)=101$ ; we can conclude that : $a^2 > 101$, also $a-2b$ and $a+2b$ have the same sign.
So, we have two set of solutions :

> 1) $b < 0$ and $a < -\sqrt{101}$
>   or
>   2) $b > 0$ and $a > \sqrt{101}$